# does not contain a constractor that takes 0 argument

Tags: c#

I know this question is already been asked but all the solution out there did not solve my problem. I have problem with inherit a class it tells me that something is missing which is I do not know, any ideas ? many thanks!!

Here is my code!

```
 public class Rectangle : Shape  (shape is an other file which is work)
{
    private Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
    private  int size; 

    protected Rectangle(Point position, int size) : base(position)
    {
        this.size = size;
    }
        public Rectangle(int x, int y, int size) : base(new Point(x, y))
    {
        this.size = size;
    }
    override public void Draw(Graphics r)
    {
        r.DrawRectangle(pen, 600, 100 , 50, 50);

    }
}

public class Square : Rectangle (here it does not work when inherit)
{
    override public void Draw(Graphics r)  
    {
        r.DrawRectangle(pen, 300, 100, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a constructor in `Square` that will call into the base `Rectangle`

```
public class Square : Rectangle (here it dose not work when inherit)
{
    public Square(Point position, int size) : base(position, size) 
    {
    }

    override public void Draw(Graphics r)  
    {
        r.DrawRectangle(pen, 300, 100, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

See the `: base(position, size)` code. Because you inherit, you also inherit the constructor of `Rectangle` so either you can do what I've done and pass arguments down to the base, or you can make `Square` parameterless but define your values: `: base(new Point(200,200), 200)`

Comment: Solved! Many many Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

`Rectangle` has two constructors.  If you are going to inherit from `Rectangle`, you *have* to be able to call into one of those constructors.  Your `Square` has to, for each constructor you have on it, be able to call into `base(Point position, int size)` or `base(int x, int y, int size)`

Comment: Solved! Many many Thanks to all!!!